# Функция добавления новой записи в структуру

Tags: c

При выводе структуры после добавления, по какой-то причине правильно отображается лишь последняя запись. Остальные блоки по неизвестной мне причине забиты либо нулями, либо непонятными символами.

```
struct name* new_record(struct name *names, int *count_names)
{
    *count_names += 1;
     if ( names  == NULL)
     {
        fprintf(stdout,"\nThe structure is empty\n");
        names = (struct name*)calloc(1,sizeof(struct name));
     }
    fprintf(stdout,"count_names = %d\n", *count_names);
    struct name new_name;

    printf("Enter the new data\n");
    printf("Enter the first name\n");
    fgets(new_name.first_name, MAX_NAME,stdin);
    new_name.first_name[strlen(new_name.first_name) - 1] = '\0';

    printf("Enter the last name\n");
    fgets(new_name.last_name, MAX_NAME,stdin);
    new_name.last_name[strlen(new_name.last_name) - 1] = '\0';

    printf("Enter the score:\n ");
    scanf("%d", &new_name.score);

    names = realloc(names,*count_names*sizeof(struct name));
    names[*count_names-1] = new_name;
    printf("\nData added\n\n");
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < *count_names; ++i)
    {    
      fprintf(stdout,"%s\t%s\t%d\n",names[i].first_name,names[i].last_name,
      names[i].score);
    }
    return names;
}
```

Прошу помочь в решении данного вопроса.

Comment: Просто вопрос - а зачем эти телодвижения с `calloc`, копированием туда-сюда? `realloc` куда приятнее. Даже если `calloc` - ну сделайте новый массив, запишите в него, а потом просто присвойте указатель на него `names`, предварительно освободив старый массив. Зачем писать во временный массив, потом, не освободив старый (утечка!) опять выделять память под массив, опять копировать... Лишняя работа.

Comment: @Harry: Этот паттерн встречается с какой-то ненатуральной повторяемостью. Подозреваю, что где-то гуляет некий "учебник", в котором насаждается эта странная манера при перевыделении памяти прогонять данные через совершенно ненужный промежуточный массив.

Comment: Спасибо, но данные в структуру почему то сохраняются некорректно. Корректно сохраняется лишь последняя строка, остальные предыдущие строки имеют сдвиг и отображаются не полностью.

Comment: В реаллоке допустил ошибку, исправил. Теперь отображается только последняя строка, все остальные строки нулевые при отображении оформлены нулями.

Answer (score 0):

У меня есть теория. Думаю, проблемма не в самой функции (её можно написать и получше, но это отдельный вопрос), а в её использовании. Я не знаю наверняка (поэтому это только теория), но подозреваю, что вы её вызываете как-нибудь так:

```
struct name *names = NULL;
int count_names = 0;

new_record(names, &count_names);
new_record(names, &count_names);
new_record(names, &count_names);
```

в то время как ваша реализация предполагает:

```
struct name *names = NULL;
int count_names = 0;

names = new_record(names, &count_names);
names = new_record(names, &count_names);
names = new_record(names, &count_names);
```

Возможно я вовсе не прав, но это объясняет столь странное поведение, о котором вы говорите.